# TypeScript font import, error with link tag property crossorigin

Tags: typescript, fonts, next.js

How can I resolve this typscript error when importing a custom font (e.g. google font).

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
```

Here the details of the error:

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2279, 9): The expected type comes from property 'crossOrigin' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>, HTMLLinkElement>'
```

---

Fix:

- the property is: crossOrigin, not crossorigin (O is capitalized)
- crossOrigin accepts a string. If you add crossOrigin in the link tag `<link ... crossOrigin />` you are writing this is a boolean (expecting a true or false) whereas it takes a string. That is why setting it to crossOrigin="anonymous" would work for example
- as since v10.2, Next.js has built-in web font optimization, meaning you can remove it and it will work

Comment: Its `crossOrigin` not `crossorigin` in JSX (as pointed by the error). Also it accepts a string not a boolean. So better set it like this: `crossOrigin="anonymous"`. Also, you don't need that for Google fonts, as since v10.2, Next.js has built-in web font optimization.

Comment: crossOrigin="anonymous" worked for me

Comment: In jsx (React) you have to write camel-case like this crossOrigin. Now you will see an error saying that it cannot be a boolean and that's correct. It must be a string of value "" (empty), anonymous or use-credentials. If any other value is given, than it falls back to anonymous. Realize that the script is initially just crossorigin without specifying anything so you will want to write this is in your jsx: crossOrigin="" or crossOrigin="anonymous"

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

did you try to write **crossOrigin** instead of **crossorigin**?

Comment: "crossorigin", only crossOrigin gives me the same error, may by a I should pass some value? crossOrigin="somevalue", but which value?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Rodrigo did you find out what value needs to be passed to crossOrigin?

Comment: @Tirias it was crossOrigin="anonymous"

Comment: thanks! also `crossOrigin="true"` made the error dissapear!

Comment: I'm working on a NextJS website and none of above solutions worked for me. I had to add the following crossOrigin={''}

Comment: <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossOrigin="anonymous" />

For me, this works. Importing Roboto Fonts

Comment: Using `crossOrigin="anonymous"` worked for me.